# How to replace a kernel on the raspberry pi to duplicate systems on sd cards?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, kernel, noobs, filesystem

I have a fully working system which is on one of my SD-cards(#1). I would like to copy everything to another sd card(#2). There are a few problems here:

1) I don't know which version of NOOB or jessie I have. So I don't know which I have to download in order to fully replicate the system

2) The approach I'd like to try: download and install the same version of NOOB or jessie (I think I have tried them all so far...) and remove the kernel from #2 and replace it with the good kernel from #1 so I have two fully identical systems.

How can I find out which version of jessie or NOOB I have?
Can I just replace the kernel with my own one?
Should I only replace kernel.img or also kernel7.img?

I am aware that those are a lot of questions all at once, but I have tried may things so far....

Thank you

EDIT:

My good sd card is divided in 2 partitions (when using linux I can see that, I can't see that when reading the SD card from my windows system ). One with the kenel image and special files while the other partition contains the linux file system. I thus tried to just naively copy everything from both partitions. However my linux system prohibits me to copy the linux file system to the second SD-card.

Comment: This all sounds *very complicated*. You're just trying to [clone one SD card onto another SD card](https://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-cards-with-windows--mac-59294) here right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you trying to replace kernel anyway?

Comment: @goobering I have an SD card of 16Gb and one of 32Gb. When I try to just  clone the content of the sd card of 32 Gb is creates an image of 30Gb, which is too big for the sd card of 16 Gb... I tried Win32 but it crashes every single time when trying to read my sd card

Comment: @Milliways how else could I do it?

Comment: @ohiliouh What is "it"? This appears to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). It seems you want to copy an image to a smaller card, so this is the question you should have asked.

Comment: A unconventional way is to make a disc image with DD and [shrink it](https://softwarebakery.com/shrinking-images-on-linux). though you will need less than 14/15GB of data on your SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download) program.

It will `Read` a card to make an .IMG file containing the entire contents of the card.  Restoring is just as simple as putting in a new card and clicking the `Write` command.

The program is OS and partition-agnostic.  It simply works with entire images of the cards.

---

Note that this is simplest.  For more demanding copies there are a couple of options, and both require the assistance of a Linux machine.

First is using `dd` to make a copy, so the source and target cards do not need to be the exact same size:

[Win32diskImager "Not enough space on disk Size: 62652416 sectors. Available: 62333952"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82347/win32diskimager-not-enough-space-on-disk-size-62652416-sectors-available-623)

Second involves actually mounting the .IMG file produces by Win32DiskImager and manipulating the internal partitions directly.

Comment: Does this work when cloning to a smaller card?

Comment: Note my answer says simplest.  What you want is not so simple, but can be done.  Moving it to a smaller card can be done, but not with this program.  Best is to actually mount the card into a Linux system then use the `dd` command to copy the partitions.  Here is a Q&A where I run through the procedure:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82347/win32diskimager-not-enough-space-on-disk-size-62652416-sectors-available-623

Answer (score 0):

Try the [rpi-clone](https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone) program. It can handle differently sized source/target. What I do is connect a USB card reader/writer to my RPi and then run this. It takes about 15 min for a 32GB card.